# Copy method of Worksheet class fails after upgrade

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

### Background:

Several years ago, I made a spreadsheet to generate a list of samples to be tested each day. The user (usually me) checks boxes to indicate which tests' samples to list. Then the "save load sheet" button uses VBA to requery a database connection for sample information, populates the formatted list through a complex series of formulas, copies the values from the formula sheet ("Generator") to another sheet ("LoadSheet"), copies that sheet to a new workbook, and saves it with the date as filename in a folder according to year and month.

It worked pretty dependably for about 5 years, right up until a couple of weeks ago when my computer was upgraded from Windows 7 with Office 2013 to Windows 10 with Office 2016.

### Problem:

Now, when I try to execute the code, I get `Runtime error '1004`: Copy method of Worksheet class failed."

```
Sub SaveAs()
    'Copy to new workbook.
    Sheets("LoadSheet").Copy  '<---This is the line that fails.

'   Check directory, create if necessary.
    If Dir("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then 
    If Dir("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then 
        MkDir ("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\")
    End If
    MkDir ("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\")
    End If

   'Save.
   'If the worksheet already exists, the user will be asked whether to replace the file or not.
   'If it already exists and is currently open, an error could arise.
   'Hopefully that won't come up before I have time to think of a way to implement error handling.
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\" &   Format(Now, "mm-dd-yy") & "x", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets(1).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Workbooks(Format(Now, "mm-dd-yy") & "x.xlsx").Activate

End Sub
```

This is the code that saves the file. It fails on the line indicated.

### What I've already tried:

- I've tried right-clicking on the worksheet tab, clicking "Move or Copy..." and try to create a copy in a new workbook. Nothing happens. No error message, no new worksheet/book, nothing.
- Same thing happens if I try to "move" rather than "copy."
- If I try right-clicking and creating a copy in the same workbook, I get a new blank sheet, rather than a copy.
- I tried repairing my Office installation, but that didn't help.
- I read about some cases where users suspected file corruption, so I even tried manually copying the contents to a new workbook by Ctrl+A,C,V one sheet at a time, and then doing the same for the code. No effect.
- I tried `Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Select` followed by `ActiveSheet.Copy`, since the sheet is the last one in the book, but of course that didn't work.
- I read that it could be because the workbook needed to be saved first, so I tried `ActiveWorkbook.Save` before the copy. Still the same result.
- I tried decompiling/recompiling the worksheet to no effect.

It worked fine on Windows 7 with Office 2013 (and still does on a co-worker's Win7/Excel2013 machine), but I couldn't find anything online about problems with the Sheets.Copy method in Excel 2016, so I don't know if either of those is relevant.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've tried it on an identical computer (also running Windows 10 & Office 2016) and had the same result. I'm not sure how commonly an installation becomes corrupted, but this feels like more than coincidence. The other computer is rarely used by anyone, and it's being used primarily to run an instance of SQL Server Express and a Windows service I wrote, so I suspect that makes corruption even less likely.

I've got a workaround for now... I just save the file with the filename and path I would have used for the copy, then do a For Each on each worksheet, deleting anything not named "LoadSheet."

```
Sub SaveAs()
On Error GoTo SaveAs_Err
'Check directory, create if necessary.
If Dir("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then  '<> "G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\" Then
    If Dir("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then '<> "G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" Then
    MkDir ("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\")
    End If
MkDir ("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\")
End If

'   Turn off alerts. They're annoying. I don't care if it's poor form, I just want to be done with this. I'm not being paid to write code.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Save, disregarding consequences.
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\" & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yy") & "x", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
'   Remove extraneous sheets.
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If ws.Name <> "LoadSheet" Then ws.Delete
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Exit Sub

SaveAs_Err:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
MsgBox ("An error occurred while saving the file.")
Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

I'm still interested in fixing the root cause of this problem, so if anyone has ideas, I'm all ears! I'll probably still try the uninstall/reinstall, but I don't expect it to change anything.

Comment: "I've tried right-clicking on the worksheet tab, clicking "Move or Copy" ... Nothing happens. No error message, no new worksheet/book, nothing" That's weird. I suspect the issue is not with your code at all. Did you do an online repair or a full uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: @Tim Our IT department installed it, so I don't have the installation disc (if such a thing is still necessary these days). I just went to the Windows 10 equivalent of the "Add or Remove Programs" list, clicked "Change," and selected the "Repair my installation" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force fix, try:

```
Sub SaveAs()
Dim newWB as Workbook, i as Integer, copyRange as Range, fName as String
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
While newWB.Worksheets.Count > 1
    newWB.Worksheets(newWB.Worksheets.Count).Delete
Wend
newWB.Worksheets(1).Name = "LoadSheet"
' get a handle on the sheet's usedRange object
Set copyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LoadSheet").UsedRange
' assign the values to the newWB.Worksheets(1)
'newWB.Worksheets(1).Range(copyRange.Address).Value = copyRange.Value
copyRange.Copy Destination:=newWB.Worksheets(1).Range(copyRange.Address)

'Check directory, create if necessary.
If Dir("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then 
    If Dir("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then 
    MkDir ("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\")
    End If
MkDir ("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\")
End If


fName = "G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\" & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yy") & "x"
If Dir(fName & ".xlsx") <> "" Then Kill fName & ".xlsx"
If Dir(fName & ".xlsm") <> "" Then Kill fName & ".xlsm"
newWB.SaveAs Filename:= fName, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Workbooks.Open(fName)

End Sub
```

Alternatively, use the `SaveAs` method of the `Worksheets` class:

```
Sub SaveAs()
Dim fName as String    
'Check directory, create if necessary.
If Dir("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then 
    If Dir("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then 
    MkDir ("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\")
    End If
MkDir ("G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\")
End If

fName = "G:\Load Sheets\" & Year(Now) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\" & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yy") & "x"
If Dir(fName & ".xlsx") <> "" Then Kill fName & ".xlsx"
If Dir(fName & ".xlsm") <> "" Then Kill fName & ".xlsm"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LoadSheet").SaveAs Filename:= fName, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks.Open(fName)

End Sub
```

I've also revised both solutions to avoid the potential error you comment:

> If it already exists and is currently open, an error could arise.

I would work with your IT and/or MS support on the specific failure of the `.Copy` method, though, it's almost certainly a problem with your installation and may result in nastier errors in the future.

Comment: @R.Harmon try now, made slight revision for that error.

Comment: I had to make another edit, too. It should be OK now, if not, let me know.

Comment: The first solution now gives me "Run-time error '1004': A workbook must contain at least one visible worksheet."

The second one now copies the entire workbook, but saves it as a .xlsx file instead of .xlsm. This is something I could work with, though it's not the direction I had originally intended.

Comment: Try first solution again, I was trying to delete all but one of the worksheets, inadvertently wrote script to delete all worksheets, which would give you that error.

Comment: Now I'm getting other error messages about the file already existing, and then about the file not being found. But it did create a new workbook with the correct data in it, albeit without any of the usual formatting.

I think you're right about the problem with my installation. I'll just have to bite the bullet... I normally try to avoid involving IT, since they usually have trouble following as I explain what I'm doing. Maybe if I just say, "My Excel is being weird, can we try reinstalling that?" As soon as I try to explain the problem, they always look like well-lit deer.

Comment: Yeah IT will not be able to debug the problem with Excel, you just need to try re-installation, so don't bore them with the details of "My .Copy method fails for no reason and I can't copy or move worksheet manually, either".  Which line is throwing error about worksheet already existing?

Comment: Made another revision to (hopefully) preserve formatting.

Comment: ahhh I see what's happening the `fName` doesn't have a file extension, so the attempt to delete/kill existing file is not working as-expected. What's the file extension?

Comment: OK, doubled up the `Kill` statements to handle both possible XLSX/XLSM variation.

Comment: @R.Harmon - +1 for the IT Department comment. I am IT for a subcontractor. I cannot tell you how much I loath contacting the contractor's first tier IT support helpdesk: http://imgur.com/gallery/aGDo2lA (HP is not our contractor, but this is pretty typical of both)

Comment: @Tim Yes, exactly! Our IT folks aren't _that_ bad, but they're more accustomed to things like "Help me connect my laptop to this projector" or (and this is a real example) "I want to demonstrate this concept to the students by projecting a hologram in the middle of the room. Just like I saw on TV. The lecture is in two weeks, so that should be plenty of time."  


I kind of feel bad for them sometimes...